# Not rendering in object mode

Tags: rendering

I'm completely new at blender and yesterday I followed a tutorial and everything turned out fine, not a single problem.
So I wanted to try and make something myself, now the only problem is, when I try to render it, I don't see the object.

Here is the .blend file:

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31320

Please keep in mind that I'm completely new.

IMG1: This is what it looks like when I choose the "Only render" option in "edit mode"

[image: This is what it looks like when I choose the "Only render" option in "edit mode"]

IMG2: This is what it looks like when I choose the "Only render" option in "object mode"

[image: This is what it looks like when I choose the "Only render" option in "object mode"]

IMG3:And this is what I see when I render it..

[image: And this is what I see when I render it..]

Answer (score 1):

Duplication options segment is for telling Blender whether it should be rendering object itself or instances of child object assigned to it.

1. Parent and child has "None" selected. Objects are rendered as in viewport:
   [image]

Parent has "Vert" selected in Duplication objects. It will be not visible. Only child Sphere instances will be rendered, without original Sphere. Sphere has to have "None" selected, as it do not have child objects assigned that could be duplicated.
[image]

In Your file, object has not any child nor parent, so it should be set to "None". "Only render" option is for viewport displaying only. When checked it displays only object that are selected to be rendered (camera icon in Scene Outliner - top, right panel). It is helpful for temporary clearing viewport from helper objects, grids, manipulators, lamps etc.

I uploaded a blend file with example: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31324

Answer (score 0):

Your object will appear if you turn off [verts duplication](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication#Procedural_Duplication):

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why this works, so hopefully somebody else can explain

Comment: It is designed to work that way [the wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliVerts#DupliVerts_as_an_Arranging_Tool) mentions that the original meshes will be seen in the 3dview but won't be rendered. Consider that a mesh with dupliverts is a particle emitter but we don't have an option to render the emitter.